# Catch SQL error on ASP 3.0 (classic) and return a specific HttpStatus

Tags: sql, error-handling, asp-classic

I'm doing some work on ASP 3.0 and haven't been able to get this down. ASP will correctly break (and return a 500 error) if there's a syntax error, but if i (on purpose) write a bad sql query and then execute the query, it will just print the returned SQL error right on the HTML, instead of breaking. This would be the code (just re-wrote the sql). Also note that this is not part of a function. It's right there on the page code.

```
set cn = server.createobject("ADODB.Connection")
cn.open sConn

sql= "select thiscolumndoesnotexist from table1 "

set rs01 = server.createobject("ADODB.Recordset")
rs01.Open sql, cn, 0
%>
```

Now, I'm sure that "On Error Resume Next" is not active, because if i break the page on ASP syntax, it will break right away. So i tried doing something like

```
On Error GoTo ErrorControl

code here..

ErrorControl:
Response.Status "500 You broke it"
Resume NExt
```

but then, the page breaks because of the `On Error GoTo ErrorControl`, right where "ErrorControl" started. As if it didn't support a named error handler.

I also tried setting `On Error Resume Next` and then `var error = Server.GetLastError()`, however, it appeared as if there was no error. I think i recall reading that Server.GetLastError would only work if no output had been sent to the client (which is my case, since it's a HTML being output, and by the time the error happens, half the document has already been sent).

Any ideas? Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I don't believe serverside VBscript supports the GOTO statement. This may help http://www.aspmessageboard.com/showthread.php?t=20090

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> As if it didn't support a named error handler.

Well yeah because it doesn't.

What you need to do is turn buffering on.   Either turn it on at the application level in IIS manager or use `Response.Buffer = True` before any content in the ASP file (static or dynamic) has been sent to the client.

Comment: hi Anthony. Thanks for the answer. Like i said, i am not that familiar with asp classic and i did read an article where they specifically mentioned (and there was even a code sample) of named error handling. I dont have the URL at hand, but can provide it later. I think it is supported for functions but not for independent code?

Comment: And your suggestion to turn Buffering on, will that make it work the way i have it? Or is that in order for me to be able to use Server.GetLastError() ?

Comment: @silverCORE:  `On Error Goto SomeLabel` is not supported anywhere in VBScript, perhaps the article you are thinking of was a) just wrong (it happens) or b) was actually about VBA or VB6 which does support it.  By turning buffering on you allow the Script engine to completely abandon the current response output and replace it with whatever is confifured to response to 500.100 errors.  You won't need to muck about Server.GetLastError etc.